# Grunt watcher for javascript concat

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate all javascript files inside my controllers directory into one file, located one level higher. This is the code I'm using:

```
concat: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/all.js': [
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/controllers/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/controllers/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine, but I'm forced to manually type `grunt concat` in console every time I change my javascript files. So I'm trying to get this done with a watcher but can't get it to work. This is my watcher code:

```
  concat: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/controllers/*.js'],
    tasks: ['concat']
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to type "grunt watch" when you want to have watch monitor the files. You'll need to add the watch task in your "Gruntfile.js" like so:

```
watch: {
  concat: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.js'],
    tasks: "concat"
  }
}
```

Your concat task still needs to be there as you currently have.

Make sure you install grunt-contrib-watch as well..

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
```

Check out the github page for grunt-contrib-watch for more info on these: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch